# Дополнительная Специализация конструктора шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, function-overloading

Пытаюсь реализовать свой дек для обучения.
Встал на следующем моменте

```
template <class T> class Deque
{
private:
    enum { defaultSize = 25, len = 5 };
    void dealloc ( );
    int alloc   ( const unsigned & = defaultSize, const T & = T() );
    T ** array;
    pair<int,int> xy;
...

public:
    Deque ( const unsigned &, const T & = T() );                       //1
    template <class Iterator> Deque (Iterator _first, Iterator _last); //2
    Deque ( ); 
    virtual ~Deque();


};
```

В main.cpp идёт создание дека:

```
Deque<int> test1(25, -1);
```

Все хорошо если нет 2-го конструктора.
Второй конструктор "перебивает" действие первого. Почему так происходит я не понимаю, ведь в конструктор передаются типы const unsigned и const int и как я понимаю компилятору следовало бы направить этот путь к первому конструктору, но он упорно использует второй...

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так.

---

**UPDATE:**

Ещё раз спасибо, всем кто ответил, разобрался и узнал новое. Позволю себе добавить некоторые уточнения, которые узнал, и которые, возможно покажутся интересными и другим. В частности, это уточнение комментария:
"
std::enable_if пишется за 10 минут на C++98, просто с C++11 это часть стандарта. SFINAE доступно довольно давно, поэтому, наиболее вероятно, как-то так и было сделано раньше. 
"

Поехали: в файле /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_deque.h, где-то в районе 899 строки будет:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      deque(size_type __n, const value_type& __value,
            const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
      : _Base(__a, __n)
      { _M_fill_initialize(__value); }
#else
      explicit
      deque(size_type __n, const value_type& __value = value_type(),
            const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
      : _Base(__a, __n)
      { _M_fill_initialize(__value); } /*--------------- #1 */
#endif


#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      template<typename _InputIterator,
               typename = std::_RequireInputIter<_InputIterator>>
        deque(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
              const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
        : _Base(__a)
        { _M_initialize_dispatch(__first, __last, __false_type()); }
#else
      template<typename _InputIterator>
        deque(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
              const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
        : _Base(__a)
        {
          // Check whether it's an integral type.  If so, it's not an iterator.
          typedef typename std::__is_integer<_InputIterator>::__type _Integral;
          _M_initialize_dispatch(__first, __last, _Integral());
        } /*--------------- #2 */
#endif
```

Т.е. видно что в 11-м стандарте (как и описывалось в сообщениях выше) используется подход метапрограммирования и шаблон, который определяет «подключать» ли данный вызов - _RequireInputIter

В 98м же Си++ используется вызов на прямую, без таких вот конструкций, типа _RequireInputIter, как я и пытался сделать изначально, следуя определению интерфейса дека.

Но наткнулся на то, что (как и было выше мне объяснено) компилятор в общем случае воспринимает конструктор

```
template<typename _InputIterator>deque(_InputIterator _first, _InputIterator __last, const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
```

как более предпочтительный (т.к. из за наличия шаблонов, в него можно «всунуть» любой тип сразу, не задействуя преобразования типов) нежели конструктор

```
deque(size_type __n, const value_type& __value = value_type(), const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
```

Но и, собственно говоря, в реализации STL для си++98 все так и получается, как получалось у меня на момент написания первого сообщения в этой теме..

Такой вызов

```
std::deque<int> dq (10,-1)
```

идёт непосредственно к конструктору ----- #2

А вот такой

```
std::deque<int> dq (10u,-1)
```

, к конструктору ----- #1

Т.е. можно говорит, что до появления std::enable_if - конструктор ----- #1 почти не использовался, а лишь служил описанием интерфейса.

А его работу исполнял ----- #2, используя для своего «двойного» поведения метод

```
_M_initialize_dispatch(__first, __last, _Integral());
```

Который, в случае если вызов объекта _Integral() имеет тип __true_type - вызывает ф-ю _M_initialize_dispatch, которая, рассмартивает первые два параметра как простые типы - первый тип размера, второй тип заполняемого значения,

Если же при инстанцировании

```
__is_integer<InputIterator>::__type
```

InputIterator не попадает ни в одну из перегруженных для __is_integer специализаций, то объект _Integral() имеет тип __false_type

И в таком случае используется перегруженная версия

```
_M_initialize_dispatch
```

, которая, переданные в неё параметры воспринимает как итераторы а не базовые типы.

И вот, таким вот образом, один конструктор, (с другим интрефейсом и как бы созданный совсем для другого) эмулирует действия первого

Убедиться в этом можно, заккоментив stl_deque.h пару строк

```
  template<typename _Integer>
    void
    _M_initialize_dispatch(_Integer __n, _Integer __x, __true_type)
    {
      //_M_initialize_map(static_cast<size_type>(__n));
      //_M_fill_initialize(__x);
    }
```

и выполнив код

```
std::deque<int> dq (10,-1);
std::copy ( dq.begin(), dq.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

собранный для -std=c++11 и -std=c++98.

Comment: а вы уверены, что тип `25` - `const unsigned` я бы сказал что все целые числа по умолчанию `int` попробуйте явно преобразовать.

Comment: @pavel: http://ideone.com/6Gf0lp

Comment: @VladD http://ideone.com/1uidjM так понятнее

Comment: Очевидно, вопрос в «более хорошем» соответствии аргументов сигнатуре. Но тут нужна ссылка на документацию про overload resolution.

Comment: Благодарю, Павел, да по умолчанию типы видимо signed. Если сделать test1((unsigned)25, -1) то выбирается первый конструктор.

Comment: `(unsigned)25` - бррррррр... `25U` же.

Comment: да 25U лучше, сразу создается нужный тип, а не идёт преобразование типа, просто заюзал, так скзазать, что чаще на языке вертелось )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Второй конструктор побеждает потому, что для первого требуется преобразование `int -> unsigned int`, тогда как для второго никаких преобразований не требуется. Самым простым вариантом избавления от этой проблемы, будет следующий:

```
template <class Iterator, typename = std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<Iterator>::value, void>::type> 
Deque (Iterator _first, Iterator _last); //2
```

Но это очень грубое решение(я имею в виду проверку `is_integral`), желательно включать этот конструктор только для итераторов, но для этого нужно знать, что является для Вас итератором.

Comment: +1, это не грубое решение. `std::deque`, судя по всему, делает то же самое (но лишь немного лучше): «This overload only participates in overload resolution if InputIt satisfies InputIterator, to avoid ambiguity with the overload (2).»

Comment: При всём уважении, что-то язык не поворачивается назвать это `самым простым вариантом`. Куда уж проще `const unsigned &` на `int` заменить.

Comment: @VladD, ну я о чём и говорю: по уму нужно делать проверку, которая захватит минимальную часть типов. Т.е. нужно выделить только итераторы, а не всё, что не интегральное.

Comment: @ixSci: Ну да, но это уже технические подробности. Главная идея в том, что неоднозначность неизбежна, и надо накладывать ограничение на параметры шаблона.

Comment: @alexolut, но это очень легко ломается: кто-то передал unsigned, кто-то `long`, кто-то `short` и т.п. С моей точки зрения, API должно быть надёжным и не должно сыпаться от таких простых вариаций, которые вполне вероятны.

Comment: @VladD, исправил ответ, придав акцент тому, что именно я считаю грубым

Comment: @ixSci: Ага, согласен, так лучше.

Comment: Visual C++ STL использует прямолинейную SFINAE для определения: http://pastebin.com/qzwEqWT6

Comment: Большое спасибо, узнал новое) Итератор у меня свой объект, по всем канонам stl, т.е. содержит описания типов, операции... Я посмотрел как такое же в stl и boost организуется, там есть аллокаторы (у меня в деке пока нет) и они тип size_type берут из аллокатора (это как раз первый параметр 1-го конструктора) ну вот, видимо этот тип должен соответствовать как раз тому что озвучил ixSci - т.е. не требовать преобразований типов.. т.е. по простому, без аллокаторов можно указать typedef T size_type; или просто в качестве типа первого параметра указывать T.

Comment: Ребят, а почему в stl и boost данный парамерт передают по значению?  [ссылка](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/container/deque.html), ведь Мейер например рекомедует "предпочитайте передаче по значению передачу константного объекта по-ссылке"

Comment: @ИльяЛесной, это рекомендация (а) _несколько_ устарела (б) применима только тогда, когда копирование jобъекта является сравнительно дорогой операцией. К примеру, имея тип `int` на x86-64, вы копируете 4 байта, а передавая ссылку, вы используете все 8 байт, т.к. ссылка это ничто иное как указатель.

Comment: Вот ведь, учу Си++ с февраля (с переменным успехом) а о таких тонкостях и не задумывался (хотя немного стыдно, т.к. до этого писал на Си, но вот не задумывался просто о таких вещах да и все, т.к. там стандартно было передать только по значению и только когда нужно - по указателю). Благодарю за очень хорошие ответы. Все понял, единственное не понял, как до 11-го стандарта с данной проблемкой справлялся stl:deque, т.е. смотрю исходники stl и не могу найти чтобы было что-то подобное remove_if, и с виду там все именно так как пытался я делать пока не знал про данную ф-ю. Как это реализовано в 98?

Comment: @ИльяЛесной, `std::enable_if` пишется за 10 минут на C++98, просто с C++11 это часть стандарта. SFINAE доступно довольно давно, поэтому, наиболее вероятно, как-то так и было сделано раньше.